# How to pass a function after the form is submitted so that I can pass the input box values to a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to know how can i pass a function after form is submitted so that i can pass the input box values to a hidden field. So for an instance if i submitted the form on page 63 and i want the value to be passed to the other page how can i do so??

Kindly throw some light on this.........

```
function validate()
{
    $('#first_name').focus();
      //  var TYUrl = $('#TY_Url').val();
       // alert($('#TY_Url'));
    var valid =true;
    var WebRequestInfo=document.getElementById('elq_form');
    if(valid && WebRequestInfo.email.value=='')
    {
            alert('Please enter your email address.');
            WebRequestInfo.email.focus();
            valid=false;
            return false;
    }

      if (valid && WebRequestInfo.first_name.value=='') {
            alert('Please enter your first name.');
            WebRequestInfo.first_name.focus();
            valid=false;
            return false;
        }


     if (valid && WebRequestInfo.last_name.value=='') {
            alert('Please enter your last name.');
            WebRequestInfo.last_name.focus();
            valid=false;
            return false;
    }

    if(valid=true)
    {



        var TYUrl = $('#TY_Url').val();
        TYUrl += "?first_name=" + encodeURIComponent($("#first_name").val()) + "&last_name=" + encodeURIComponent($("#last_name").val())   + "&email=" + encodeURIComponent($("#email").val());


    $('#TY_Url').val(unescape(TYUrl));                                       
       document.forms[0].submit()

    }

return valid;
}
```

Comment: If the form is submitted, the page reloads, and all javascript is lost.

Comment: have you tried submitting the form through ajax?

Comment: for everyone here is the form created on this page: info.cvent.com?elqpurlpage=63. kindly submit the form and see what happens which helps you get a better understanding on my perspective

Answer (score 0):

For client-Side , you could use cookies to save these data. Then on every page reload you could load them. 
You can find here how to use cookies with javascript : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Another way could be to use session data but you need to do some server side work there.

Comment: I just want to pass some values like first name, last name and email and append it to the to the other page url. So I am trying to do two things:  1.  Validate function will check if all the fields returned. 2. once the data entered and someone clicks on submit I would like to pass a function.

Answer (score 0):

How about localStorage for HTML5? Data will be saved on client side.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp